# Ошибка импорта проекта

Tags: eclipse, c++

Импортировал я проект с существующим исходным кодом и `Makefile` через мастер создания соответствующего проекта в Eclipse. Поскольку проект рабочий? то компилируется и исполняется он на ура, но редактор кода показывает ошибки. С некоторыми из них я справился подключив заголовочные файлы в настройках проекта. Но одну понять не могу =(. А именно: >Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved.

Точно такая-же ошибка появляется и для `endl` и для других членов пространства имен `std`.

P.S: Вызываются cout и endl так: std::cout, std::endl.

Comment: @greshnik Какой эклипс вы используете?

Comment: Самый последний eclipse indigo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавив все include из helloworld проекта в мои проект ошибки с cout и endl пропали! Остались только непонятные ошибки связанные с getopt. В данном коде:

```
const struct option long_options[] = {
    { "configfile", required_argument, 0, 'C' },
    { "data",       required_argument, 0, 'd' },
    { "default",    no_argument,       0, 'D' },
    { "playername", required_argument, 0, 'p' },
    { "password",   required_argument, 0, 'P' },
    { "help",       no_argument,       0, 'h' },
    { "updatehost", required_argument, 0, 'H' },
    { "skipupdate", no_argument,       0, 'u' },
    { "username",   required_argument, 0, 'U' },
    { "no-opengl",  no_argument,       0, 'O' },
    { "version",    no_argument,       0, 'v' },
    { 0 }
};
```

Eclipse ругается на required_argument и no_argument хотя в getopt.h они определены.